# parse complex Gson , nested inner class was not parsed

Tags: android, gson

I use gson.fromJson(jsonStr, JVisitorResponse) method to parse the JSON reponse string, **all were parsed except the inner class JUserUrls**, there must be something wrong, my wrong usage of Gson caused this, please help me.

My outer reponse class defined below:

```
public class JVisitorResponse extends BaseResponsePojo {

    public int count;

    @SerializedName("visitor_list")
    public ArrayList<JVisitor> visitorList;

    public JVisitorResponse() {
    }   
}
```

JVIsitor class defined below:

```
public class JVisitor {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    public long uid;
    @SerializedName("user_name")
    public String userName;
    @SerializedName("user_urls")
    public JUserUrls userHeadUrls;
}
```

JUserUrls class defiend below:

```
public class JUserUrls {
    @SerializedName("main_url")
    public String mainUrl;
}
```

my JSON response was

```
{
    count:30,
    visitor_list:[
        {
            user_id:333333,
            user_name:"jason lee",
            user_urls:{
                main_url:"http://xxxxxxxxxx.jpg"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Works fine for me, I can get `main_url` from your class. Please show how do you get this field

Comment: In which class class JUserUrls is inner class ??

Comment: @nikis String headUrl = item.userHeadUrls.mainUrl; i got headUrl for null value

Comment: @bhutto in JVisitor class as an inner class

Comment: @jason and how do you get `item`?

Comment: @nikis i use fromJson method, and then got item from JVisitorResponse's field visitorList(ArrayList)

Comment: the following is working for me fine: `gson.fromJson(json, JVisitorResponse.class).visitorList.get(0).userHeadUrls.mainUrl`

Comment: @jason It's work fine for me. I am able to get main_url. can you show that piece of code how you are getting this filed

Comment: @bhutto ,my code was same to yours@nikis, gson.fromJson(json, JVisitorResponse.class).visitorList.get(0).userHeadUrls.mainUrl,why i got null and u got the correct value?

Comment: @nikis, thanks very much for your answer, it's my fault that i didn't notice that the server was not stable,sometimes it return null value, and sometimes it return the full url. sorry to waste your time.